# Java app keeps freezing Firefox

Tags: firefox, java

I'm using this java based applet at work and for the last two days when I click the link to open the app it opens fine and loads everything up until the login part which doesn't show up. At this point it is a guarantee that the app has frozen Firefox. No matter how long I let it load, it gets nowhere. The frustrating part is that it sometimes loads fine!

Luckily I have a unix program that runs through the server to run some of the things I need the app to do so I'm not wasting a lot of time, but I HAVE to get this working more consistently.

I have the latest version of Firefox, 14.0.1, and the latest version of Java, Version 7 Update 6. I even went in and removed the old version of Java to see if it would make a difference which it has not. I also have previously verified this source with Java and I believe it is the same every time since a new one doesn't come up each time I open it.

When I ran the java console to check for errors and to see what happens this is what it returns

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.main(Unknown Source)
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Queue.waitForMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter$1.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.Waiter.runAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.message.Pipe.receive(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.server.HeartbeatThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PLEASE HELP! MOMMY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an old XP desktop at work, I had a similar issue where I resolved it by dumping the java temp files.  Something in the cache was causing funkiness after an upgrade.  Not sure what OS you are using, but this could be done from the Java Control Panel.  It may be worth the 30 seconds it will take to try.

Comment: thanks your the only person on either forum that said anything positive or constructive! i will try it out next time it freezes, which it will

Comment: It shouldn't hurt anything if you clean that out anyhow.. and if it ever does hang or crash again, then you know I was wrong.

Comment: would it be bad if I did it while the app is currently running? sounds like a no no to me

Comment: Yeah, prob would not help at all.  Just do it while the app is closed the next time you have it closed.

Comment: this actually did help, since I don't know what the problem is yet, I'll wait a little to pick your answer as correct